# $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n \ $ converges then show that $ \ |a_n|<1 \ $

Tags: sequences-and-series

$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n \ $ converges  then show that $ \ |a_n|<1 \ $

**Answer:**

If not let $ \ |a_n|>1 \ $

Then the partial sum is $ \ s_n=|a_1|+|a_2|+....+|a_n| \ $

Let $ \ n>m \ $, then

$ |s_n-s_m|=|a_m|+|a_{m+1}|+........+|a_n|> (n-m) \ $

since $ \ n>m $ , we have $ \ n-m \geq 1 \ $

This shows that

$ |s_n-s_m| \nrightarrow \ 0 $

This implies $ s_n \ $  is not Cauchy .

Therefore $ \ \sum a_n \ $ diverges.

Which is a contradiction.

Thus we must have $ \ |a_n|<1 \ $

**Am I right so far?**

Comment: Your question lacks the values for $n$ (i.e., if $a_0=1000$ and for $n\geq 1, a_n=0$ then the series converges but $|a_n|<1$ is not true for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$).

Comment: What do you mean, $|a_n| < 1$? If you mean, "for all $n$", then the result is clearly false. If you mean, "for some $n$ or eventually for all $n$", this is a consequence of the divergence test: $a_n \to 0$.

Comment: That means after a certain stage $ \ |a_n| <1 \ $

Comment: That follows because for $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (a_n)$ to converge we must have (though not sufficient) $\lim_{n \to \infty} (a_n) = 0$ (WHY ?). Thus the result follows (HOW ?)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show that $|a_n|<1$ **after a certain stage** then **NO** your answer does not hold because the logical negation of:
$$
\exists N\in \mathbb{N}, \forall n\geq N, |a_n|<1
$$
is not:
$$
\exists N\in \mathbb{N}, \forall n\geq N, |a_n|>1
$$
but rather:
$$
\forall N\in \mathbb{N}, \exists n\geq N, |a_n|>1
$$
In other words, if you are going [reductio ad absurdum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reductio_ad_absurdum) (which is perfectly legitimate), you may use the fact that if there were infinitely many $\Phi(n)$ so that $|a_{\Phi(n)}|>1$ then since $\sum_n a_n$ converges, $\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n = \lim_{n\to \infty} a_{\Phi(n)}=0$. The contradiction follows.

Comment: Would those who downvoted care to explain? Thanks in advance.